# Jssor - grabbing element by index

Tags: javascript, jssor

I have a question about grabbing and image from Jssor slider. I have a carousel with 20 images (9 of them visible at a time) and I need to grab the middle one (to add or remove a class). I want to add an effect where the middle one is in color, and the rest are grayed out. How could I do that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please do this job in following manner,

```
var currentHighlightIndex;
function SliderParkEventHandler(slideIndex) {
    if (currentHighlightIndex != undefined) {
        //remove previous highlight
    }

    //highlight current slide
    currentHighlightIndex = slideIndex;
}
```